Can you please explain why speed varies unevenly in my PCIe throughput?
I'm working on an experiment where I transfer data to and from an NVMe SSD connected via a PCIe Gen1 x1 interface using an FPGA. The data transfer starts at a maximum speed of 295 MBps but drops to 214 MBps after some time. I'm trying to understand if this drop in speed is due to cache limitations in the SSD, an issue with the PCIe interface, or possibly an error in my code that calculates transfer rates. How can I debug this issue in my code or identify if the problem is related to the caching mechanism of the SSD?

While you didn't provide enough data for a conclusive answer, your observations are consistent with a lower grade SSDs.
These devices have a smaller SLC fast storage where they quickly store a burst of incoming data and their main storage is a cheaper TLC or QLC where writing is slower.
The data from the SLC area is transfered to the main storage in periods of inactivity or when SLC is full.
This works well because the typical usage pattern of an SSD has a lot of idle periods and the device can keep its fast area ready. If you push it with a lot of data to write, you will feel the slowdown.
Sometimes there is a second slowdown to an even lower speed, it happenns when the thermal management kicks in.

I'm using Samsung 970 Evo plus SSD. Is that a lower grade SSD? I'm having the same problem in that too ,the following are the output...
Time [s], Rate [MB/s], Total [GB]
1,     256.901,      0.257-----Data write to LBA 0007A800:00
2,     196.084,      0.453-----Data write to LBA 000D8000:00
3,     196.084,      0.649-----Data write to LBA 00135800:00
4,     196.084,      0.845-----Data write to LBA 00193000:00

from my experience 970 evo is way faster
